# Security is disabled, why and how to configure the security.context?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and I've created a [custom user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) and everything works fine so far except for that following message shows:

[image: Profiler photo]

Weird thing is that for example in Twig I can do:

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

And it prints fine the username of the logged user.

I've tracked the printing of that message in this [view](https://github.com/symfony/SecurityBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Collector/security.html.twig) and this is the corresponding [controller](https://github.com/symfony/SecurityBundle/blob/2.3/DataCollector/SecurityDataCollector.php).

Seems that the class `SecurityDataCollector` is initialized with a parameter of type `SecurityContextInterface` with a value of `$this->get('security.context', ContainerInterface::NULL_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE)`

The problem seems to be that `security.context` does not exists and I don't know how to set that security context and in the example they don't set them. How can I fix this?

---- app/config/security.yml ----

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    encoders:
        Company\Shared\CompanyldapBundle\Security\User\ldapUser: plaintext

    providers:
        ldap_user_provider:
            id: ldap_user_provider

    firewalls:
        main:
            provider: ldap_user_provider
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path:  login
                check_path:  login_check
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Do you use the `FosUserBundle` or a custom UserBundle? How have you set up the `app/config/security.yml`? Could you post yours as well?

Comment: I'm using a custom UserBundle, I have updated the answer to include my `app/config/security.yml`. Thank you!